# Docusign Invalid E-Mail

Tags: xml, docusignapi

I'm receiving an "INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT" error when submitting the following XML to the DocuSign API. I have tried manually changing the address and using different addresses for each signer. Why does the request return an invalid address when I can send an e-mail to any of the addresses I've tried an e-mail directly?

```
String [] emailaddr4 = new String {"cts@companyname.com", "me@companyname.com", "next@companyname.com", "last@companyname.com"};

String xml = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
               "<accountId>" + accountId + "</accountId>" +
               "<status>sent</status>" +
               "<emailSubject>" + emailSubject + "</emailSubject>" +
               "<emailBlurb>" + emailBlurb + "</emailBlurb>" +
               "<templateId>81bcad0d-****-****-****-f281b24a4567</templateId>" +  
               "<templateRoles>" +
                   "<templateRole>" +
                       "<email>" + emailaddr4[0] + "</email>" +
                       "<userName>" + emailaddr4[0] + "</userName>" +
                       "<name>" + names[0] + "</name>" +
                       "<roleName>Student</roleName>" +
                       "<clientUserId>1</clientUserId>" +
                       "<tabs>" +
                           "<textTabs>" +
                               "<text>" +
                                   "<tabLabel>sid</tabLabel>" +
                                   "<value>" + student_id + "</value>" +
                               "</text>" +
                           "</textTabs>" +
                       "</tabs>" +
                   "</templateRole>" +
                   "<templateRole>" +
                       "<email>" + emailaddr4[1] + "</email>" + 
                       "<name>" + names[1] + "</name>" + 
                       "<roleName>Advisor</roleName>" + //must match role in envelope
                       "<userName>" + emailaddr4[1] + "</userName>" +
                       "<routingOrder>1</routingOrder>" +
                   "</templateRole>" +
                   "<templateRole>" +
                       "<email>" + emailaddr4[2] + "</email>" + 
                       "<name>" + names[2] + "</name>" + 
                       "<roleName>DeptHead</roleName>" + 
                       "<userName>" + emailaddr4[2] + "</userName>" +
                       "<routingOrder>2</routingOrder>" +
                   "</templateRole>" +
                   "<templateRole>" +
                        "<email>" + emailaddr4[3] + "</email>" +
                        "<name>" + names[3] + "</name>" + 
                        "<roleName>Dean</roleName>" +
                        "<userName>" + emailaddr4[3] + "</userName>" +
                        "<routingOrder>3</routingOrder>" +
                   "</templateRole>" +
               "</templateRoles>" +
           "</envelopeDefinition>";
```

Here is the actual XML that is written to the DataOutputSteam

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
    <accountId>******</accountId>
    <status>sent</status>
    <emailSubject>This is a test.</emailSubject>
    <emailBlurb>Java DS Test</emailBlurb>
    <templateId>81bcad0d-****-****-****-f281b24a4567</templateId>
    <templateRoles>
        <templateRole>
            <email>desk@test.edu</email>
            <userName>desk@test.edu</userName>
            <name>Tester</name>
            <roleName>Student</roleName>
            <clientUserId>1</clientUserId>
            <tabs>
                <textTabs>
                    <text>
                        <tabLabel>sid</tabLabel>
                        <value>6644</value>
                    </text>
                </textTabs>
            </tabs>
        </templateRole>
        <templateRole>
            <email>desk@test.edu</email>
            <name>Alan advisor</name>
            <roleName>Advisor</roleName>
            <userName>desk@test.edu</userName>
            <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
            </templateRole>
        <templateRole>
            <email>desk@test.edu</email>
            <name>CTS</name>
            <roleName>DeptHead</roleName>
            <userName>desk@mtech.edu</userName>
            <routingOrder>2</routingOrder>
        </templateRole>
        <templateRole>
            <email>desk@test.edu</email>
            <name>Jennifer</name>
            <roleName>Dean</roleName>
            <userName>desk@test.edu</userName>
            <routingOrder>3</routingOrder>
        </templateRole>
    </templateRoles>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

This is the response when requesting template recipients.

```
<recipients xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <agents/>
    <carbonCopies/>
    <certifiedDeliveries/>
    <editors/>
    <inPersonSigners/>
    <intermediaries/>
    <recipientCount>4</recipientCount>
    <signers>
        <signer>
            <recipientId>9d44f02b-****-****-****-db256768d013</recipientId>
            <recipientIdGuid>9d44f02b-****-****-****-db256768d013</recipientIdGuid>
            <requireIdLookup>false</requireIdLookup>
            <roleName>Student</roleName> 
            <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
            <status>created</status>
            <templateLocked>false</templateLocked>
            <templateRequired>true</templateRequired>
            <email/>
            <name/>
            <signInEachLocation>false</signInEachLocation>
        </signer>
        <signer>
            <recipientId>3a1f0ff1-****-****-****-bbecca30dc1a</recipientId>
            <recipientIdGuid>3a1f0ff1-****-****-****-bbecca30dc1a</recipientIdGuid>
            <requireIdLookup>false</requireIdLookup><roleName>DeptHead</roleName>
            <routingOrder>3</routingOrder>
            <status>created</status>
            <templateLocked>false</templateLocked>
            <templateRequired>true</templateRequired>
            <email/>
            <name/>
            <signInEachLocation>false</signInEachLocation>
        </signer>
        <signer>
           <recipientId>2dd69109-****-****-****-4773cabe5632</recipientId> 
           <recipientIdGuid>2dd69109-****-****-****-4773cabe5632</recipientIdGuid>
           <requireIdLookup>false</requireIdLookup>
           <roleName>Advisor</roleName>
           <routingOrder>2</routingOrder>
           <status>created</status>
           <templateLocked>false</templateLocked>
           <templateRequired>true</templateRequired>
           <email/>
           <name/>
           <signInEachLocation>false</signInEachLocation>
       </signer>
       <signer>
           <recipientId>085d8e2c-****-****-****-bdd92344e257</recipientId>
           <recipientIdGuid>085d8e2c-****-****-****-bdd92344e257</recipientIdGuid>
           <requireIdLookup>false</requireIdLookup><roleName>Dean</roleName>
           <routingOrder>4</routingOrder>
           <status>created</status>
           <templateLocked>false</templateLocked>
           <templateRequired>true</templateRequired>
           <email/>
           <name/>
           <signInEachLocation>false</signInEachLocation>
       </signer>
   </signers>
</recipients>
```

Comment: Can you update your question to post the XML trace of the actual request that's being sent over the wire?  (You can easily produce a request trace using a tool like Fiddler or something similar.)

Comment: @KimBrandl Kim I updated the original question with the filled in version of the code hopefully that provides more information.

Comment: Repro'd your issue and suggested a solution in my answer.

Comment: @KimBrandl After your suggestion I have double and triple checked that the API request roles and template roles match exactly. I have even removed the spaces that I originally had in the role names and updated my XML to match. I have also downloaded the the template XML from the dashboard and verified that everything matches there. 
Then I copied the template and tried using the new template id. In addition I pulled a backup from when this was working and it does not work either. I still receive the invalid e-mail error. Any more suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please try doing a "Get Recipients" API request for your Template (https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{templateID}}/recipients?include_tabs=false&include_extended=false) and then update your question to include the response?  If you can do this, I'll take a look and may be able to offer some additional feedback.

Comment: @KimBrandl I have include the full response for https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/‌​{{templateID}}/recipients?include_tabs=false&include_extended=false let me know if there is anything else you need.

Comment: Please see my updated answer below. 2 of the role names in your create envelope request are wrong.

Comment: @KimBrandl These are the ones I mentioned in my comment above I have updated the first and second code sections containing the modifications. My apologies.

Comment: I'm not sure if something has changed in the development system recently, but I know for sure this worked around the 18th of Feb 2014.

The role names matched when I started having this trouble. I changed them and they do match now I just forgot to update the originally posted code sets.

Comment: Added "Update #2" to my answer.

Comment: @KimBrandl Thank you so much for your help. I added more information to your answer as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce this error message if I attempt to create/send an Envelope using a Template, where the Template specifies each Recipient Role as **required**, but I don't specify correct/complete recipient role names in my Create Envelope request.

For example, my template in DocuSign specifies two Recipient Roles -- **Signer1** and **Signer2** -- both of which are required:

[image: DS Recipient Roles]

As a side note -- if I do a **Get Recipients** API request for the template, the response also shows that both recipient roles are required (**templateRequired=true**):

```
{
    signers: [
        {
            signInEachLocation: "false"
            name: ""
            email: ""
            recipientId: "f1b5d256-d85c-42d3-b081-913fb93e13a7"
            recipientIdGuid: "f1b5d256-d85c-42d3-b081-913fb93e13a7"
            requireIdLookup: "false"
            routingOrder: "1"
            roleName: "Signer1"
            status: "created"
            templateLocked: "false"
            templateRequired: "true"
        }
        {
            signInEachLocation: "false"
            name: ""
            email: ""
            recipientId: "79e8bc34-6a40-4cc5-90e1-e58d9707418e"
            recipientIdGuid: "79e8bc34-6a40-4cc5-90e1-e58d9707418e"
            requireIdLookup: "false"
            routingOrder: "2"
            roleName: "Signer2"
            status: "created"
            templateLocked: "false"
            templateRequired: "true"
        }
    ]
    agents: [ ]
    editors: [ ]
    intermediaries: [ ]
    carbonCopies: [ ]
    certifiedDeliveries: [ ]
    inPersonSigners: [ ]
    recipientCount: "2"
}
```

Now let's assume that I send the following "Create Envelope From Template" API request, and use the wrong role name for the second recipient:

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
   <accountId>a673cd1a-***-****-****-6f4bf80e54sd</accountId>
   <status>sent</status>
   <templateId>3C9D42D3-3E76-4669-861E-9670415E1AD3</templateId>
   <templateRoles>
      <templateRole>
         <email>johnsemail@outlook.com</email>
         <name>John Doe</name>
         <roleName>Signer1</roleName>
      </templateRole>
      <templateRole>
         <email>janesemail@outlook.com</email>
         <name>Jane Doe</name>
         <roleName>RoleNameDoesntMatchWhatTheTemplateSpecifies</roleName>
      </templateRole>
   </templateRoles>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

The response contains this error:

```
<errorDetails xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <errorCode>INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT</errorCode>
    <message>The email address for the recipient is invalid. The recipient Id follows.</message>
</errorDetails>
```

Based on this testing, I'd suggest that you verify that your "Create Envelope" API request is specifying Recipient information for all required Recipient Roles that the Template defines, and also that the value of `<roleName>` for each recipient in your API Request ***EXACTLY*** matches (including both spelling AND case) the role name that's defined in the Template.

**** -------- UPDATE #1 - 3/6/2014 ---------- ****

Thank you for updating your answer to include the "Get Recipients" response for the Template that you're having trouble with.  That response shows that the Template defines 4 Recipient Roles:

```
<roleName>Student</roleName> 
<roleName>DeptHead</roleName> 
<roleName>Advisor</roleName> 
<roleName>Dean</roleName>
```

Your "Create Envelope From Template" request supplies information for 4 Recipient Roles -- BUT 2 of the 4 role names in the request are incorrect (i.e., do not match the role names defined by the Template).  Here are the roles you're supplying in your "Create Envelope From Template" request:

```
<roleName>Student</roleName>
<roleName>Advisor</roleName>
<roleName>Dept Head of Major</roleName>
<roleName>Dean of School</roleName>
```

To resolve the error you're getting, you need to make the Role Names in your "Create Envelope From Template" request match exactly with the Role Names that your Template defines.  i.e., in your "Create Envelope From Template" request, you need to change the following:

- Change <roleName>**Dept Head of Major**</roleName>   to   <roleName>**DeptHead**</roleName>
- Change <roleName>**Dean of School**</roleName>   to   <roleName>**Dean**</roleName>

**** -------- UPDATE #2 - 3/6/2014 ---------- ****

To troubleshoot further, I'd suggest that you:

- Edit the Template in DocuSign to make each Recipient Role *not* required -- i.e., for each recipient role, **uncheck** the "Sender Cannot Delete Recipient" checkbox (shown in 1st screenshot of my original answer). Save the template after making this change for all four of the recipient roles.
- Next, submit your "Create Envelope" API Request.  If the request succeeds (i.e., no error response), then this supports my suspicion that the Recipient info in your Request is somehow not matching up with the Template roles. (Even if that's the case -- i.e., no error -- you still need to figure out which role is causing the problem, because even though your API request was able to successfully create the Envelope, it likely did so with only SOME of the four recipients -- the roles that didn't match will have been dropped from the Envelope).

Next, to figure out which role is causing the problem:

1. Edit the Template to **check** the "Sender Cannot Delete Recipient"
   checkbox for the first role, and Save the Template.
2. Next, submit your "Create Envelope" API Request.  If the request
   succeeds (i.e., no error response), then the role you just made
   required is **not** the one causing the problem.  If the request
   fails (i.e., error message "INVALID E-Mail"), you've found the role
   that's causing your problem.  In that case, I'd probably try deleting the role
   from the Template, adding it back to the Template again, -- then
   verify that the role name matches EXACTLY (case-sensitive) what
   you're sending in the API Request, and re-attempt the API request.
3. Go back to Step 1 and repeat this process for the next role in the template...keep repeating until you've done these steps for all 4 roles (i.e., all 4 roles are once again required by the Template).

Comment: The suggestion to turn of the requirement for each role was awesome. I didn't realize that could be done or that it was set. The problem ended up being that the routingOrder in the XML did not match the routing order of the roleName in the dash board/template. The routingOrder must match what is in the template.

Comment: Glad to hear you've figured it out -- thanks for the update. As a side-note -- I don't think you even need to supply the Routing Order for each recipient in the Create Envelope API request (since the Template already specifies routing order for the recipients).